# Migrating to Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, driver

My project is using ***Microsoft JDBC Driver 3.0*** for SQL server. Since then Microsoft has included the ***Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0*** version and my client has sought for the advantages of the new version over the current. Also they want to know if there any compatibility issues that need to be addressed.

Our current system employs Java 1.6, WAS 7.0, Hibernate 3.0 and MS SQL Server 2000 on Windows Server 2008.

Please let know the advantages and issues of migrating to ***Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0*** version with respect to the above configuration especially **SQL Server 2000**. The client has no thoughts of changing/upgrading the database from SQL Server 2000 as its huge and involves great risk.

Will a driver change to Version 4.0 from 3.0 will have any benefits if the underlying database is still SQL Server 2000.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted this, but I suppose it's because your question doesn't show any sign of research. You're supposed to do research yourself and then ask questions pertaining to problems you have encountered, rather than present open-ended questions and expect others to provide you with research results. Then again, I'm just hypothesizing here.

Comment: i have updated the question to be more specific on the details i am looking for. The question is not specific to the advantages of migration but whether the migration will benefit a system that i am using.

Answer (score 2):

Please [follow this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378749%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) .You can see all the new features and changes w.r.t to **version 3.0 to 4.0**.They just added new support for different things like some datatypes time , date , datetime2, datetimeoffset.Some byte level accesses and **column behaviour change**.AFAIK if you migrate your driver then it will not create issues for you because this driver also contains previous version support as well.

Comment: but keep in mind that migration should be towards updated version

Comment: thanks..will it work for MS SQL Server 2000 database ??

Comment: please see this http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774 you will know that it is only supporting these servers.
    Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012,
    Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2,
    Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008,
    Microsoft® SQL Server® 2005,
    Microsoft® SQL Azure

Comment: **From the docs** : The JDBC driver has been designed specifically to use features introduced with SQL Server 2005, but it is `backward-compatible with SQL Server 2000`, including the 64-bit version

Comment: Yes It can be .. You have to take a test look for this :) but As much as Microsoft told I reffered you :) .. Please accept the answer if you think tha it helps